# How to use multiple error specific parameter in custom Exception constructor parameters?

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, runtimeexception

I am building a custom exception something like this.

```
public class ValidationException extends RuntimeException {

    public validationException(String errorId, String errorMsg) {
        super(errorId, errorMsg);
    }
}
```

This of course throws error because **RuntimeException** doesn't have any such constructor to handle this.

I also want to fetch the errorId and errorMsg in my **GlobalExceptionalHandler** by

> ex.getMessage();

But I want functions to fetch both the errorId and errorMessage separately. How can this be achieved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to the `errorId` and `errorMsg` as fields of ValidationException class, just like you would do with a normal class.

```
public class ValidationException extends RuntimeException {

    private String errorId;
    private String errorMsg;

    public validationException(String errorId, String errorMsg) {
        this.errorId = errorId;
        this.errorMsg = errorMsg;
    }

    public String getErrorId() {
        return this.errorId;
    }

    public String getErrorMsg() {
        return this.errorMsg;
    }
}
```

and in your GlobalExceptionHandler:

```
    @ExceptionHandler(ValidationException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<SomeObject> handleValidationException(ValidationException ex) {
        // here you can do whatever you like 
        ex.getErrorId(); 
        ex.getErrorMsg();
    }
```